# How Do I change the list-syle in page/sidebar?

Tags: css, sidebar

Using wordpress.

I would like to the change the style of my lists in the main page as well as the sidebar. Right now I have a little circle with an arrow in it. I'd rather have it be just a black circle in the main page and I'd like there to be nothing before the text in the sidebar.

I've looked everywhere for the code but can't find it. I figured it would be in the sidebar1.php or sidebar2.php files but I haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with WordPress per se, so I'll just try to point you in the right direction until someone comes along who can answer more specifically.

This is typically handled in CSS. I'd imagine there's some external stylesheet like Style.css or Theme.css that provides styling for your app. This may be found in the root of the app, a folder named Styles or something similar, or in a subfolder structure representing the theme(s) you are using.

`list-style: none;` will remove bullets altogether

`list-style-type: square;` will make bullets square

`list-style-image:url("/images/image.gif");` will use an image you provide.

Do the php files specify a style class for these elements? If not, the stylesheet may be using their ID.

If you can find the stylesheet(s) for your site, find or create the entries for the lists in question.

For example: `ul.sidebar1` or `#sidebar1 ul` (something along those lines,) and modify the rules to your liking.